# Translating 3-dimensional array reference onto 1-dimensional array

Tags: c++, c

If there is an array of ar[5000] then how could I find where element [5][5][4] would be if this was a 3 dimensional array? Thanks

I'm mapping pixels:
imagine a bimap of [768 * 1024 * 4]
where would pixel [5][5][4] be?

I want to make this:

```
static GLubyte checkImage[checkImageHeight][checkImageWidth][4];

static GLuint texName;
bool itt;
void makeCheckImage(void)
{
    Bitmap *b = new Bitmap(L"c:/boo.png");

    int i, j, c;
    Color cul;

    for (i = 0; i < checkImageHeight; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < checkImageWidth; j++) {
            b->GetPixel(j,i,&cul);


            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) cul.GetR();
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) cul.GetG();
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) cul.GetB();
            checkImage[i][j][3] = (GLubyte) cul.GetA();
        }
    }
    delete(b);
}
```

work without making a multidimensional array.
width = 512, height = 1024....

Comment: I think you need to know the array dimensions to answer this question

Comment: Do you know the fixed sizes of two of the dimensions?

Comment: For bitmaps, you'll need to know whether each channel (i.e. the 4) is stored as a contiguous block or whether the pixels are stored as individual blocks. (Band interleaving or pixel interleaving) What format are you working with?

Comment: Given your example, that pixel would be: 5+(5*1024)+(4*(1024*768)) = 3150853... Slightly beyond the bounds of your original array ;)

Comment: It depends on how the image is laid out in memory. It probably is an `array[768][1024][4]`. That's where all the confusion comes from I guess :)

Comment: @FredOverflow yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[x * z_size * y_size + y * z_size + z] worked

Answer (score 7):

That will depend on the dimensions of the imaginary three dimensional array as well as how its laid out. Sometimes the formula is `ar[z * x_size * y_size + y * x_size + x] == ar[z][y][x]`, but without knowing the size of each dimension and what order they're in, there's no way to tell for sure.

Comment: Fair enough, JAB. I'll change that.

Comment: I need x y z though, im trying to map textures in OpenGL

Comment: Swap 'x' and 'z' in the above example? It's not materially different is it?

Comment: @cyborg: If you're not replacing *every* instance of `ar[z][y][x]`, having exact matching is necessary.  Otherwise, translations, rotations, etc. have no effect (except perhaps on memory locality).

Comment: I think he's responded in one of the answers but basically what I was getting at is that if he wants to reorder the x, y and z it's just a renaming exercise - presuming he has control over his data structures. (Which looks like the case from the question).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know the size of the dimensions. If you wish to interpret it as a `ar[m][n][p]` array, such that `mnp=5000`, `ar[5][5][4]` would correspond to `ar[5*m*n+5*n+4]`.

This is because C++ works in *row-major order*.